# busybox option is always (NEW)

Tags: linux, config, uclinux

The issue I'm having is that every time I alter a busybox configuration setting (using menuconfig), I get asked the same question during the build:

```
udhcp Client with zeroconf support (CONFIG_UDHCPC_ZEROCONF) [N/y/?] (NEW)
```

If I update the default vendor settings, the values in busybox's .config file get written to my vendor file. For example if I change `CONFIG_UDHCPC=y`, my vendor config file (vendors/MyCo/MyProd/config.vendor-x.x.x) will be updated with `CONFIG_USER_BUSYBOX_UDHCPC=y`.

This doesn't happen for the `CONFIG_UDHCPC_ZEROCONF` option. I tried manually adding `CONFIG_USER_BUSYBOX_UDHCPC_ZEROCONF=y` to my vendor config file, but still get asked the question.

So my question is: How are other options transferring between the .config and the config.vendor file, but that one in particular is not? I don't know enough about the configuration build system to find the answer.